# Haswell HD graphics 4000 - Monitor doesn't sleep on power off

Tags: windows-7, display, sleep

I have new PC with Haswell HD graphics 4000 connected to a Dell HD display via HDMI cable

The monitor that came with my computer doesn't sleep on shutdown or computer standby. This is particularly annoying since it's an LCD, so the monitor is black but the backlight is still on

I have Gigabyte H87M-HD3 board and didn't find any reference to DPMS  signals configuration

I read somewhere that the mouse can be related - I have remove it/ update driver

Nothing help